# How to create Report: My Accounts and My Account Team Accounts

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, joined-reports

I'm trying to create a report that shows me all Accounts where a User is the Owner, along with all Accounts where the same User is an Account Team member.

Out of the box, the 'Accounts with Account Team' report type does not deliver on the former, and the good ol' 'Accounts' report type does not deliver on the latter.

I created a custom report with Accounts (left joined) Account Teams, but what I'm looking for is more of a 'Union' than a left join.

How can I create a single report to deliver this information?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Joined Report: [Combine Different Types of Information in a Joined Report](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_working_with_joined.htm&language=en_US).